# Communicating to database from microcontoller

Tags: database, communication, microcontroller

I would like to communicate to a database (simple queries, just reading and writing to db) from micro-controller which has TCP/IP stack implemented on (uIP). I'm now a bit confused which protocol should be used for this?

Is is possible to use HTTP for safe communication?

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP is just a transport protocol, a way to move data from one place to another.  Use whatever *data protocol* is most convenient for your particular application.  If you need to be able to pass the data through firewalls, XML or JSON are excellent choices.

Comment: Is it possible to manage it with HTTP protocol? I have a some sample code for this so I would save a lot of time if it could be done.

Comment: Like I said, you can use whatever data protocol you want.  HTTP, however, is optimized for *display.*

Answer (score 0):

HTTP might be overkill, I'd consider something like http://redis.io this article might help a bit http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/04/simple-arduino-tcp-client-using-the-ethernetshield-dhcp-and-a-java-server/